# Indexing footnotes as a toc

Tags: footnotes

I am using two kinds of footnotes:

1. To show english equivalent of a term.
2. To explain something in more detail or to refer to the required section.

I want to have an index of the first-type footnotes at the end of my document like a toc (or like a four column table with 2 pairs of english/equivalent headers). Do we have a package or command for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`endnote`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/endnotes.html) package and define a special command for making a note into both a footnote and an endnote.

```
\newcommand{\mynote}[1]{\footnote{#1}\endnote{#1}}
```

Or you can just use the index package [`makeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/makeidx.html), if you want it ordered alphabetically.

```
\newcommand{\mynote}[1]{\footnote{#1}\index{#1}}
```

The second works like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\mynote}[1]{\footnote{#1}\index{#1}}
\begin{document}
the red colour\mynote{color in american english} here
\printindex
\end{document}
```

You have to run `latex` (or `pdflatex`) twice and also `makeindex` for sorting the output, so saving the above as `mwe.tex`, execute the following:

```
pdflatex mwe
makeindex mwe
pdflatex mwe
```

If you are using a special TeX-editor like Kile oder TeXnicCenter, there might be options to enable this behavior.

There are possibilities to change the layout of the index, using index style files and document class specific functions, but that would probably be a different question.

Comment: Should I use it Like \mynote{Text}? Using it this way, gives me the error "index type 'default' undefined". I am using the second command.

Comment: Yes, something like `the red colour\mynote{color in american english} here`.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a minimal working example of the second. I am still receiving the error "index type 'default' undefined"

Comment: OMG, I was using the index package "\usepackage{index}" :D. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I improved the markup. Btw backticks for marking code are also possible in comments.